# R group by multiple columns and mean value per each group based on different column

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

data set exist data with `age, gender, state, income, group`. Group represents the group that each user belongs to:

```
     group      gender state age       income
 1       3      Female  CA     33  $75,000 - $99,999
 2       3        Male  MA     41  $50,000 - $74,999
 3       3        Male  KY     32  $35,000 - $49,999
 4       2      Female  CA     23  $35,000 - $49,999
 5       3        Male  KY     25  $50,000 - $74,999
 6       3        Male  MA     21  $75,000 - $99,999
 7       3      Female  CA     33  $75,000 - $99,999
 8       3        Male  MA     41  $50,000 - $74,999
 9       3        Male  KY     32  $35,000 - $49,999
10       2      Female  CA     23  $35,000 - $49,999
11       3        Male  KY     25  $50,000 - $74,999
12       3      Female  MA     21  $75,000 - $99,999
```

Above is dummy data and goal is to get the concept correct.

The goal is to group by `group, gender, income` and get the count and for each group get the mean age from the users who belong to that group. Then set the data in following structure: "Expanded Version"

```
    group  male female CA  MA  KY  $35,000 - $49,999  $50,000 - $74,999 $75,000 - $99,999  mean_age
     2      0     2     2   0   0          2                1              0                   23
...
```

Here are the attempts: using `dplyr`

```
> data %>% group_by(group, 
+ gender, 
+ state, 
+ income) %>% 
+ summarize(n()) %>% 
+ mutate(mean_age = mean(age))
```

I was also exploring `spread` function.

Answer (score 1):

You can do both the count and mean in one call to `summarize()`:

```
library(dplyr)    

data %>% group_by(group, 
                  gender, 
                  state, 
                  income) %>% 
  summarize(count = n(), mean_age = mean(age))
```

For the wide data, the variable names in your sample won't uniquely identify what a given data point means since the unique units are `group X gender X state X income` but it only has one row per `group`.

Since you have two summaries, the summary type is an additional layer to the unique identification. So to get everything in one row you would have variable names like `[group]_[gender]_[state]_[income]_[summary]`. For example, `2_Female_CA_$35,000 - $49,999_count`.

There may be a better wide shape - what type of calculations are you doing on the wide data frame?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @treysp's answer you could use `unite` and `spread` to create a wide (and unwieldy) table. (I'm using `as.data.frame()` only to force printing all columns).

```
require(tidyverse);
df %>%
    group_by(group, gender, state, income) %>%
    summarize(n = n(), mean_age = mean(age)) %>%
    unite(key, gender, state, income) %>%
    spread(key, n) %>% as.data.frame();
#  group mean_age Female_CA_$35,000 - $49,999 Female_CA_$75,000 - $99,999
#1     2       23                           2                          NA
#2     3       21                          NA                          NA
#3     3       25                          NA                          NA
#4     3       32                          NA                          NA
#5     3       33                          NA                           2
#6     3       41                          NA                          NA
#  Female_MA_$75,000 - $99,999 Male_KY_$35,000 - $49,999
#1                          NA                        NA
#2                           1                        NA
#3                          NA                        NA
#4                          NA                         2
#5                          NA                        NA
#6                          NA                        NA
#  Male_KY_$50,000 - $74,999 Male_MA_$50,000 - $74,999 Male_MA_$75,000 - $99,999
#1                        NA                        NA                        NA
#2                        NA                        NA                         1
#3                         2                        NA                        NA
#4                        NA                        NA                        NA
#5                        NA                        NA                        NA
#6                        NA                         2                        NA
#
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "group      gender state age       income
 1       3      Female  CA     33  '$75,000 - $99,999'
 2       3        Male  MA     41  '$50,000 - $74,999'
 3       3        Male  KY     32  '$35,000 - $49,999'
 4       2      Female  CA     23  '$35,000 - $49,999'
 5       3        Male  KY     25  '$50,000 - $74,999'
 6       3        Male  MA     21  '$75,000 - $99,999'
 7       3      Female  CA     33  '$75,000 - $99,999'
 8       3        Male  MA     41  '$50,000 - $74,999'
 9       3        Male  KY     32  '$35,000 - $49,999'
10       2      Female  CA     23  '$35,000 - $49,999'
11       3        Male  KY     25  '$50,000 - $74,999'
12       3      Female  MA     21  '$75,000 - $99,999'", header = T, row.names = 1)
```